# Is this website legit (adhering to SE license), or illegal scraper?

Tags: support, policy

http://htmlasks.com/which_predictions_of_the_force_awakens_darths_amp_droids_bingo_were_correct

vs

[Which predictions of the Force Awakens: Darths & Droids Bingo were correct?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112251/which-predictions-of-the-force-awakens-darths-droids-bingo-were-correct/112254#112254)

Comment: I don't see any mention of StackExchange or any links to SFF.SE anywhere on that site (even in view code mode), except when one of the answers contains such a link in user-written text. So that seems like a very unambiguous failure to attribute, no matter how you interpret the license's attribution requirement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it most certainly is not adhering to the SE license. Nowhere on that page is there a mention of Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange, any mention of the CC-BY-SA license, a link to the original question, or a link to the profile of the asker, all of which are (at least as far as SE claims) requirements for mirroring their content.

You should [report this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) in the usual place as described here:

[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)

(summary: the "contact us" page has a special option just for this purpose.)